# Find sibling-pods (pods deployed by the same deployment)

Tags: kubernetes

I run an application which needs a list of all client ips for synchronization. I run this application in Kubernetes and make requests against `https://kubernetes/api/v1/pods` from these client-pods. So I am searching for a reliable way to identify all pods, which are created by the same deployment (replication set) this way.

Thereby it is important, that the pods are also identified correctly during a rolling-upgrade.

I do have a couple of ideas I want to share, even that none really convinces me:

**1) Using labels (`?labelSelector=label=value`):**

1.a) Define a **custom label** only these pods have: Valid solution, but since the solution should be really general, I don't want to define a special label, the pods need to have. Also this way I can not be sure to add other pods which got the label.

1.b) Use the auto-generated **pod-template-hash** label: Sadly this one gets changed during a rolling-update, so which the update takes place, the selector does not work correctly.

**2) Using custom fields (`?fieldSelector`)**

I thought of using either a subpart of the `name` or `ownerReference.name` attributes. Sadly the fieldSelector is [badly documented](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15128__) or does not work at all. I also thought of parsing the full list of pods via `jq`, but don't really like the dependency.

**3) Identify all pods by referencing a common service**

I see now way to recognize which pod belongs to which service (beside using labels again)

---

Are there any other ideas to identify sibling-pods? I am kind of surprised that I did not find a simular question.

Comment: Labels/Selectors are really what you’re looking for. Use `kubectl get rs [name] -o=yaml` and take a look at `selector:` field.

Comment: Of course, normally selection should be done using labels. While I am still suprised that there is no generic way to select siblings, after talking to some colluegues, I recognized there just isn't and labels are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

That is what the `app` selector is typically used for.

You can use kubectl to list pods for a deployment.

The following is from the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/):

> List the pods created by the deployment:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=nginx

  NAME                                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS  
  AGE  nginx-deployment-1771418926-7o5ns   1/1       Running   0        
  16h  nginx-deployment-1771418926-r18az   1/1       Running   0
```

You can also list Pods by yaml file:

`$ kubectl get pod -f ./pod.yaml`

Comment: This only works if you actually declared the `app` label in your pod spec or used `kubectl run` command (which implicitly adds the label).

Comment: That is correct, but still would be considered the standard way of doing what you are trying to achieve I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to follow up on this by sharing a solution that I've devised that depends on labels and utilizes `jq` (I realize the OP was specifically not asking for `jq` solutions but I think this is neat).

```
// extracts all pod labels and organizes them in a selector
sel=${$(kubectl get deployment --output=json my-deployment | jq -j '.spec.selector.matchLabels | to_entries | .[] | "\(.key)=\(.value),"')%?}

// list pods using the selector above
kubectl get pods --selector=$sel
```

I borrowed ideas from the `kubectl` cheat sheet - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/